# Hibernate logging

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, configuration

My application uses Hibernate with Ehcache.

I have configured log4j with this log4j.properties:

```
# Configure the console as our one appender
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, A1

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info
### log HQL query parser activity
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=info
### log just the SQL
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=info
### log JDBC bind parameters ###
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=info
### log schema export/update ###
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=info
### log HQL parse trees
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql=info
### log cache activity ###
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=info
### log transaction activity
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.transaction=info
### log JDBC resource acquisition
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=info
### enable the following line if you want to track down connection ###
### leakages when using DriverManagerConnectionProvider ###
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider=info
```

But in console output i have very much log lines like this:

```
22:42:06.603 [Thread-15] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration imm_time -> org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@1bdedf8
22:42:06.603 [Thread-15] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration imm_timestamp -> org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@5264dc
22:42:06.603 [Thread-15] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration imm_dbtimestamp -> org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@15bd8eb
22:42:06.603 [Thread-15] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration imm_calendar -> org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@fe4dd2
22:42:06.603 [Thread-15] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration imm_calendar_date -> org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@1a751ff
22:42:06.603 [Thread-15] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration imm_binary -> org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@1f86f75
22:42:06.603 [Thread-15] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration imm_serializable -> org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@15daaef
22:42:06.603 [Thread-15] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration materialized_blob -> org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType@9d5241
22:42:06.604 [Thread-15] DEBUG n.s.e.config.ConfigurationFactory - Configuring ehcache from InputStream
22:42:06.606 [Thread-15] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.BeanHandler - Ignoring ehcache attribute xmlns:xsi
```

Is it possible to disable this DEBUG messages? I can not find any working solution.
Thanks in advance!

PS. pom.xml contains only:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem:
1. exclude commons-logging from spring:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

2. setup logging with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

3. exclude logback from reflections:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5-RC2_jboss-SP1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I'm sorry if I gave few details :)

Answer (score 0):

```
log4j.appender.A1.Threshold=INFO
```

Try the above and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Is it possible that Hibernate is using a log4j configuration of its own? This usually happens if your log4j.properties is present much lower on the classloader hierarchy than Hibernate's.

Comment: my log4j.properties is placed in src/main/resources, i.e. WEB-INF/classes in resulting war

Comment: And where is hibernate jar placed? WEB-INF/lib or somewhere else?

Comment: Is there also a commons-logging jar present in it?

Comment: yes it present as dependency of spring, i think this is the problem, but if i exclude commons-logging i will get errors in compile time

Comment: this DEBUG messages looks like they are printed not with log4j, but with java.util.* logging

Comment: @adarshr let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3009/discussion-between-sergey-vedernikov-and-adarshr)

Comment: There is a good article on how to solve this on [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) site.